# Property not found when returning to original state in flex

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

My application uses an API to get a list of movies out of a database, when the user selects a movie he gets details about this movie. Now I added a back button which lets the user return to the orignal start state. ( from state_details to state_start ). However when I then select a new movie I get an error saying:

> ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property moreInfo not found on
>   spark.skins.spark.ApplicationSkin and there is no default value.  at
>   customComponents::MovieRenderer/___MovieRenderer_Image1_click()[C:\Users\User\Adobe
>   Flash Builder
>   4.6\Project_RMA\src\customComponents\MovieRenderer.mxml:51]

I have tried different things to get this to work but without any luck. The application is able to find the property moreInfo at the initialization of the application. It first loads the current popular movies and clicking on one to get more info works just fine. But then when you back out of that object, it gives an error it can't find the property anymore.

Here is some code:

moreInfo :

```
        public function moreInfo(movieData:Movie, fromMoreInfo:Boolean = false):void
        {       

            currentState = "state_details";
            lblTitle.text = movieData.title;
            moviePoster.source = movieData.image;

         }
```

when clicking on the image ( in item renderer ) it calls to moreInfo

```
<s:Image width="170" height="170" x="-4" y="-4" source="{movieData.image}" click="parentDocument.moreInfo(movieData, fromMoreInfo);"></s:Image>
```

Hopefully that is enough code to get it solved.

EDIT:

There is a button on state_detail where I change the state back to start in it's eventhandler.

```
protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            currentState = 'state_first';   
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having your itemrenderer instances calling things on your main container directly, I'd refactor to dispatch events from your itemrenderer and have the application act on that:

```
<s:Image width="170" height="170" x="-4" y="-4" source="{movieData.image}" click="dispatchEvent(new DataEvent(MOVIE_DATA_SELECTED,false, false, movieData.id));"></s:Image>
```

In your main application file, add this to your `creationComplete` listener:

```
movieList.addEventListener(MyItemRenderer.MOVIE_DATA_SELECTED, onSelectMovie);
```

Also add this function:

```
public function onSelectMovie(e:DataEvent):void {
    var movie:Movie = lookUpMovie(e.data); //e.data is the movie ID
    moreInfo(movie, true);
}
```